# CNN model not working well on 4 species but works well with 2 species

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I tried CNN model on two classes and got 80% but when i tried the same model with 4 classes i got very bad result. What is the reason pls help.
The model of CNN i used is:

```
model= Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

#opt = SGD( lr=0.01)

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples//batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data = validation_generator, 
    validation_steps = validation_generator.samples // batch_size,
)
```

The result of 2 classes something like this i lost the actual result of it:

```
Epoch 29/35
46/46 [==============================] - 188s 4s/step - loss: 0.6511 - accuracy: 0.5880 - val_loss: 0.7534 - val_accuracy: 0.5175
```

The result with 4 classes is:

```
46/46 [==============================] - 367s 8s/step - loss: -10550614391401.7266 - accuracy: 0.2541 - val_loss: -15023441182720.0000 - val_accuracy: 0.2354
```

Comment: some of the item in your 3rd and 4th class are not normlaized, may be wrong image data is corret but some issues with data, also yout last layer output should be `categorical_crossentropy`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The output layer is using `sigmoid` activation function which can be used only for binary classification problems.

For more than two classes, use `softmax` activation function and the dense layer before it should have `num_of_classes` nodes.

```
model.add(Dense(numclasses)) # numclasses = 4 in your case
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

Also the loss should be changed from `binary_crossentropy` to `categorical_crossentropy` (this is the main reason for weird loss displayed in your case).

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

**Note :** `categorical_crossentropy` expects `one-hot` vectors. If the labels you have is just a 1D array rather than an one-hot vector, use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`

Comment: Sir, after changing to categorical i got this error:

ValueError: You are passing a target array of shape (20, 1) while using as loss `categorical_crossentropy`. `categorical_crossentropy` expects targets to be binary matrices (1s and 0s) of shape (samples, classes). If your targets are integer classes, you can convert them to the expected format via:
```
from keras.utils import to_categorical
y_binary = to_categorical(y_int)
```

Alternatively, you can use the loss function `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` instead, which does expect integer targets.

Comment: sorry, I thought your output will be one-hot vector... Change the `categorical_crossentrophy` to `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`

Comment: mark it s the correct answer if it solved your issue

Answer (score 3):

You network with 4 classes should look like this

```py
model= Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3),input_shape=input_shape))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(4 activation='softmax'))

#opt = SGD( lr=0.01)

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

loss should be `categorical_crossentropy` and last layer should be `softmax` with `4` possible outcomes.

Comment: No, the layer before softmax should never be 1 neuron. This would bring several adverse effect and will reduce the model accuracy greatly.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, that was mistake, I have modified and removed invalid layer.

Answer (score 2):

**Difference between Sigmoid and Softmax**

Difference between Sigmoid and Softmax function in deep learning
Softmax function can be understood as a generalized version of a sigmoid function or an extension of a sigmoid function. Softmax function is usually used in the output layers of neural networks.

Following are some of the differences between Sigmoid and Softmax function:

**1.** The sigmoid function is used for the two-class (binary) classification problem, whereas the softmax function is used for the multi-class classification problem.

**2.** Sum of all softmax units are supposed to be 1. In sigmoid, it’s not really necessary. Sigmoid just makes output between 0 to 1. The softmax enforces that the sum of the probabilities of all the output classes are equal to one, so in order to increase the probability of a particular class, softmax must correspondingly decrease the probability of at least one of the other classes.

When you use a softmax, basically you get a probability of each class (join distribution and a multinomial likelihood) whose sum is bound to be one. In case, you use sigmoid for multi-class classification, it’d be like a marginal distribution and a Bernoulli likelihood.

**3 Formular for SoftMax function**

[image: Formular for SoftMax function]

**4 Formular for Sigmoid function**

[image: Formular for Sigmoid function]

Let me illustrate the point 2 with an example here. Lets say, we have 6 inputs:

[1,2,3,4,5,6]

If we pass these inputs through the sigmoid function, we will get following output:

[0.5, 0.73, 0.88, 0.95, 0.98, 0.99]

Sum of the above output units is 5.03 which is greater than 1.

But in case of softmax, the sum of output units is always 1. Lets see how? Pass the same input to softmax function, and we get following output:

[0.001, 0.009, 0.03, 0.06, 0.1, 0.8] which sums up to 1.

**5.** Sigmoid is usually used as an activation function in hidden layers (but we use ReLU nowadays) while Softmax is used in output layers

A general rule of thumb is to use ReLU as an activation function in hidden layers and softmax in output layer in a neural networks.

for more details [here](http://theprofessionalspoint.blogspot.com/2019/05/activation-squashing-functions-in-deep.html)

So you have to use softmax activation function and categorical cross-entropy as the loss function for multi-class classification cases.